# Taking a screenshot of a page running WebGL using puppeteer

Tags: webgl, puppeteer, cesiumjs

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a page that is running webGL based Cesium. If I just take the screenshot, the page will be loaded, but the webGL wont be finished loading.

If I use the built in `networkidle0` or `networkidle2`, the screenshot is never taken. Here is my code.

And here is the website I'm trying to take a picture of: https://www.arelplane.com/@arelenglish

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = {
  takeScreenshot: (userId) => {
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
          '--headless',
          '--hide-scrollbars'
        ]
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://www.arelplane.com/@arelenglish', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
      await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

      await browser.close();
    })();
    return "Successful API call!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is saying `headless: false`, along with an argument called `--headless` which means `headless: true`. Puppeteer will get confused.

Jokes aside, here is what I saw on the network tab.
[image]

The network tab says it loads at least 66 requests with at least or more than `1.5s` for each resource (idk why it loaded slower on my default chrome).

Same from a [page load test (click to see the report)](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.arelplane.com/uB0USwsS), which basically says it loads 170+ requests for around 40+ seconds.

[image]

The default timeout is 30 seconds, but it loads data for 90+ seconds.

Here is the argument to deal with navigation timeout.

```
await page.goto('https://www.arelplane.com/@arelenglish', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0", "timeout": 0}); // timeout: 0 will disable navigation timeout
```

Either disable the timeout or increase it to say 120 seconds or something around that range. Here is my code,

```
puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.arelplane.com/@arelenglish', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0", "timeout": 0});
  await page.screenshot({path: "test.png"});
  await browser.close();
});
```

and here is the result,
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Getting rid of the timeout solved the problem!